# Keeping columns on the bottom

Tags: css

I am trying to bring the **.day_line** columns on the bottom of **.lines_container**. I tried to set extra **.lines** in the .day_line colmn and give them

```
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0
```

and to parent

```
 position:relative;
```

but it doesn't push the lines on the bottom...

Any reason/solution?

My codes here http://jsfiddle.net/BqDfn/

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container is going to keep that fixed height, you could do this:

```
.day_line {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question very well, but i guess you want those strips to go all the way down, if so set the `Height: 100%`

```
.day_line{
   float:left;
   margin-left:50px;
   position:relative;
   width:10px;
   height:100%; // Changed to 100%
   background:red;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```